# C# - Como fazer um filtro lambda com mais de um campo?

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Minha Lista:

```
public class Carro
{
   public int Ano;
   public double Valor;
}

List<Carro> Fiat = new List<Carro>();
Fiat.Add(new Carro {Ano = 2000, Valor = 5000 });
Fiat.Add(new Carro {Ano = 2000, Valor = 6000 });
Fiat.Add(new Carro {Ano = 2001, Valor = 7000 });
Fiat.Add(new Carro {Ano = 2002, Valor = 8000 });
```

Como fazer um filtro nessa lista usando lambda com mais de um campo?

Comment: Depende, que filtro você quer fazer? Filtro de que? Mostre pelo menos como você faria com um campo para entendermos o que quer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crie a função a baixo e passe como paramentos da função os valores que você quer filtrar

```
    public List<Carro> Filtrar(List<Carro> lista, int Ano, double valor)
    {
        List<Carro> lstFiltrada = lista.Where(x => x.Ano == Ano && x.Valor == valor).ToList();
        return lstFiltrada;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Carros de 2003 para baixo com valor maior que 5000:

```
var lista = Fiat.Where(c => c.Ano <= 2003 & c.Valor > 5000);
```